# Unknown android error

Tags: java, android

can someone help me with the code, simulation suddenly stops when i press calculate(button). the code is to basically add 3 numbers using 3 different edittext(etjan, etfeb, etmar) then compute the commission(in the if...else, etcom) and then find the total(etpro).

```
package com.example.personal.semifinals_exam;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
// import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  EditText etJAN, etFEB, etMAR, etTS, etCOM, etPRO;
  //TextView txtO_TS, txtO_COM, txtO_PRO;
  Button btnCALC/*, btnADD, btnDELETE, btnCLEAR*/;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etJAN =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etJAN);
    etFEB =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFEB);
    etMAR =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMAR);

    btnCALC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCALC);
    btnCALC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        String Jan, Feb, Mar;
        double com, tc;

        Jan = etJAN.getText().toString();
        Feb = etFEB.getText().toString();
        Mar = etMAR.getText().toString();

        double jan = Double.parseDouble(Jan);
        double feb = Double.parseDouble(Feb);
        double mar = Double.parseDouble(Mar);

        double ts = jan + feb + mar;

        etTS.setText(ts + " ");

        if(ts <= 299) {
          com = 0.00;
          tc = ts * com;
          etCOM.setText("No Commission");
          etPRO.setText((tc + ts) +" " );
        }
        else if (ts > 299 && ts < 1000) {
          com = 0.10;
          tc = ts * com;
          etCOM.setText("10% Commission");
          etPRO.setText((tc + ts) +" " );
        }
        else if (ts > 999 && ts < 1500) {  
          com = 0.20;
          tc = ts * com;
          etCOM.setText("20% Commission");
          etPRO.setText((tc + ts) +" " );
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your logcat output with the stacktrace.

Comment: Did you get `etTS` and also `etCOM` `etPRO` instances ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review this [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to initialize **etTS, etCOM, etPRO** then use the `setText`:

```
etTS =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTS);
etCOM =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCOM);
etPRO =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPRO);
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize etTS, etCOM, etPRO in your code, first initial them like what you do for etJAN, etFEB, etMAR then try set value to them ...